# Specific Heat Capacity and Thermal conduction of Blood

Tags: zoology, red-blood-cell

Is the specific heat capacity and thermal conductivity of animal blood (e.g., steer for beef) and bird blood (e.g., broilers, ducks) [e.g., immediately after slaughter] similar/same as human blood?

I found regarding human blood:

Specific heat capacity = $3300-3900$ Jkg$^{-1}$ $^\circ$C$^{-1}$ (average $3617$ Jkg$^{-1}$ $^\circ$C$^{-1}$) (https://itis.swiss/virtual-population/tissue-properties/database/heat-capacity/)
(For Americans that's $0.788-0.93$ BTUs lb$^{-1}$F$^{-1}$) (average $0.86$ BTUs lb$^{-1}$F$^{-1}$).

Thermal conductivity = $0.49-0.56$ Wm$^{-1}$ $^\circ$C$^{-1}$ (average $0.52$ Wm$^{-1}$ $^\circ$C$^{-1}$) (https://itis.swiss/virtual-population/tissue-properties/database/thermal-conductivity/)
(For Americans that is $0.2848-0.3248$ BTUs hr$^{-1}$ft$^{-1}$F$^{-1}$) (average $0.3$ BTUs hr$^{-1}$ft$^{-1}$F$^{-1}$).

Is this the same/similar for animals and birds? Where can I find this info?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: I have no evidence, but I'd suspect so, the compositions are very similar.